# Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) on SVN commit

Tags: svn

I can update SVN well, but when I try to commit, I'm getting the following error:

> Error while performing action:
>     Commit failed (details follow):
>     Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to PUT request for '/svn/!svn/wrk/89ff070d-5fb0-4a77-9609-0fd87964d712/project/trunk/templates/operator/default/settings.tpl'

Any idea why I can't commit? Other team members can commit without trouble.

Comment: You might need to look in the event log of the subversion server to see what the content of the 500 error is.

Answer (score 0):

First of take a look at the protocol you're using to connect to the SVN server - you're using `http` or `https` you can be certain that svn is configured to work oven a web server (apache or nginx or etc.). Then the logs on the server will be in the relevant web server's log directory. This is the case if the server was not specially configured. Concrete logging configuration resides in your `subversion.conf`

Find the logs the answer you're looking for is in there.